# Is there any way to get a better terminal in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

I'm using emacs for python, and I'd like to have a nice useable shell in emacs to run an interpreter alongside my editing.

Is there any better emacs shell package out there? The default shell is awful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You say "terminal" in the title and "shell" in the question, yet you refer to an interpreter.  It's all rather confusing.

If you want a better Python interpreter than the standard (although I'd suggest you explore the features of python-mode first); check out [ipython.el](http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/ipython.el) which will give you an IPython interface.

If you want a better terminal, try `M-x ansi-term`, which will give you colors, etc.

If you want a better shell, are you using eshell?  You can use your standard shell with `M-x shell` or `M-x ansi-term` as above.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what shell you are using, in GNU Emacs 23 there are at least 3 built in:

- shell - ugly, not working tab
- eshell - not ugly but tab not working
- term - not ugly and seems like ipython works with all goodies in it

So you might want to try the term mode.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Gabriel Elanaro's collection of extensions to emacs for python](https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python) on github.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid future confusion between shell, terms and interpreters in Emacs, [it might be worth reading this article first](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/11/01/running-shells-in-emacs-overview/).